# Can't connect Huawei Watch to android studio on windows 7

Tags: wear-os, huawei-mobile-services

I have tried everything. Googled to every corner and I am surprised no one reports this. That makes me all the more worried.

I am trying to connect the huawei watch to my pc to develop on android wear. Android studio doesn't see my watch and on device manager I see Other Devices-->Huawei Watch with a yellow notification icon to indicate there is a problem.

I naturally googled with the likes of "Huawei driver windows 7". There is nothing that is not a spam or a trojan designed to further kick me in the buns.

Any one has any indicator as to what to do ? . I can't debug through bluetooth

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? In my case, the device is not visible to the computer at all.

Comment: sadly no :( . i had no time to investigate and I went along painfully through the bluetooth debugging option.